# Get PHP-arraylist for all different attributes in a database table

Tags: php, mysql

I got all entries of a database table with PHP. Now I want an array for every different attribute of a specific column; if the attribute is the same, it should be in the same array. Look at the example below to understand what I mean:

```
+----+-------------------+------+
| ID | ColA              | Colb |
+----+-------------------+------+
| 1  | Some Text         | 2    |
+----+-------------------+------+
| 2  | Text              | 4    |
+----+-------------------+------+
| 3  | Another Text      | 2    |
+----+-------------------+------+
| 4  | Just Text         | 4    |
+----+-------------------+------+
| 5  | Text Text         | 4    |
+----+-------------------+------+
| 6  | Another Text Text | 4    |
+----+-------------------+------+
```

The array should look like this after the mechanism which I'm looking for:

```
Array (2) {
  Array (2) {
     Array (ID => '1', ColA => 'Some Text', ColB => '2'),
     Array (ID => '3', ColA => 'Another Text', ColB => '2')
  },
  Array (4) {
     Array (ID => '2', ColA => 'Text', ColB => '4'),
     Array (ID => '4', ColA => 'Just Text', ColB => '4'),
     Array (ID => '5', ColA => 'Text Text', ColB => '4'),
     Array (ID => '6', ColA => 'Another Text Text', ColB => '4')
  }
}
```

I know how to solve this with a for-loop, but is there a one-code-line-way? MySQL or PHP-funciton?

Comment: You can get pretty close with PDO's `FETCH_GROUP` mode for the `fetchAll()` method. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#88699

Answer (score 0):

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

$db = mysql_select_db("expDB", $con);

$sel = mysql_query("select * from exp order by ColB");

$a = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel)){

$a[$row['ColB']][] = $row;

}

print_r($a);